# how to create crawled property for a custom field

Tags: search, enterprise-search, managed-property, crawled-property

As title above, i want to create a crawled property for one custom field which is taxonomy field. Some information about this field are as bellow:

1. Display Name: Document Category
2. Static Name: DocumentCategory
3. Internal Name: Document_x0020_Category
4. Type: Taxonomy

I did try this powershell code block :

```
New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -Category SharePoint -IsNameEnum $false -Name "owstaxId_DocumentCategory" -PropSet 158d7563-aeff-4dbf-bf16-4a1445f0366c -SearchApplication "Search Service Application" -VariantType 31
```

and this code block with `-Name` is `owstaxId_Document_x0020_Category`

They were created successfully with a warring in powershell:

> Warning: obsolete parameter ignored: '-variantType'

Then, I manually map the crawled property for `DocumentCategory` and start a full crawl.

Finally, I go to search center and search with :

```
DocumentCategory:"xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
```

xxxx-xxxx is the termId, but it returns nothing.

I do not really know exact which step i did make wrongly. Could you please give me some idea? I just want to create crawled and managed property for a custom taxonomy field.

Answer (score -1):

Try use the Search Query Tool (https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) - open advanced mode on the left side and click the checkbox. Then do a search for your item. Then in primary results click on "view all properties" and verify that your property is in the collection and what value it contains.